# What do each of the str-function abbreviations/acronyms mean?

Tags: c, string, naming-conventions, abbreviation, string.h

The C standard library `string.h` contains several functions to manipulate strings, all of which start with `str` and end with an abbreviation. Some of these abbreviations are obvious:

- `strlen` *string length*
- `strcpy` *string copy*
- `strcmp` *string compare*

Some are a bit less straightforward:

- `strpbrk` *string pointer break?*
- `strspn` *string ...spn?*
- `strrchr` *string ... R char??*
- `strxfrm` *string... um... nevermind.*

What do each of the `str`-function abbreviations/acronyms mean?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- `strlen` - find LENgth of string
- `strcpy` - CoPY strings
- `strcmp` - CoMPare strings
- `strrchr` - Reversely find CHaRacter
- `strspn` - calculate the length of SPaN of characters
- `strxfrm` - TRANS (written as X)-FoRM a string
- `strpbrk` - find the Point where string is BRoKen by any of the characters